# みんな and おかね pitch accent in 関西弁

Tags: pitch-accent, kansai-ben

I think in 標準語 both words are 平板型: みんな{LHH}, おかね{LHH}

I just heard みんな{HLL} and おかね{HLL} in a conversation among native speakers (younger generation, from various places), and wondered if they were doing a 関西弁 impression.

Comment: みんな can be both odaka and heiban in 標準語 :) 副詞的用法の場合，アクセントは [0]. In NHK dictionary, there are two entries for みんな.

Comment: @firuvi Interesting! thanks!

Comment: みんな is usually 尾高. When it is used as an adverb, no particle follows it for pitch to go down on. Not sure if it means it has two accent patterns.

Comment: @aguijonazo The reason some dicts like to specifically list it as [0] for the adverb usage is because it behaves differently from an odaka noun directly followed by a verb (店＼行く、家＼行く, as well as stuff like 山＼あり谷＼あり (tho やまあ＼り is also heard) etc). But separating out the adverb form as [0] does sort of unnecessarily complicate the model because that's how all adverbs behave, and honestly the fact it changes to heiban is more likely to be a syntactic/intonation phenomenon as opposed to really something about the lexical accent changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be an awful impression. They are [みんな]【LHL】 and [おかね]【LLH】

Comment: Is there any well-known dialect in which those are pronounced as 頭高型? I think I heard おかね{HLL} or おかね{HHL} repeated by several people in the conversation, so I wasn't sure if the humor evaded me.

Comment: @EddieKal - Not sure about these particular words but at least some of the Niigata dialects use 頭高 a lot.